# Mapping Shift-Up & Shift-Down, mintty keycodes

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

I am trying to create some keybinds (in my *.vimrc*) for *vim*, used from Cygwin's *mintty*.

I have found and extended some code for the *.vimrc* that translates the keycodes used by *mintty* (https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Keycodes) back into the correct input.

```
for [key, code] in [
        \["<F1>", "\eOP"],
        \["<F2>", "\eOQ"],
        \["<F3>", "\eOR"],
        \["<F4>", "\eOS"],
        \["<F5>", "\e[15~"],
        \["<Home>", "\e[H"],
        \["<End>", "\e[F"],
        \["<S-Up>", "\e[1;2A"],
        \["<S-Down>", "\e[1;2B"],
        \["<S-Right>", "\e[1;2C"],
        \["<S-Left>", "\e[1;2D"],
    \]
    execute "set" key."=".code
endfor
```

Most of these work fine, but when I press shift and the down-arrow in insert mode, *vim* simply prints *[1;2A*, similar for Shift-Down. What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Are you pressing shift-down in insert mode? normal mode? other? Please [edit] to clarify. If you're new to stackexchange, I also recommend the [tour] and the [help].

Comment: In insert mode, clarified this in my question. (Actually, I'm trying to set vim up to be modeless, so everything happens in insert mode ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with mintty, but a quick google search returned the following:

### 1. [mintty tips](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Tips#unexpected-behaviour-with-certain-applications-eg-vim):

> ### Unexpected behaviour with certain applications (e.g. vim)
>
> If for example the PgUp and PgDn keys do not work in your editor, the
>   reason may be that in the mintty Options, the Terminal Type was set to
>   "vt100" and based on the resulting setting of the environment variable
>   TERM, the application expects other key sequences than mintty sends.
>   (While mintty could be changed to send VT100 application keypad codes
>   in that case, the current behaviour is compatible with xterm.)
>
> (...)
>
> #### Avoiding escape timeout issues in vim
>
> It’s a historical flaw of Unix terminals that the keycode of the
>   escape key, i.e. the escape character, also appears at the start of
>   many other keycodes. This means that on seeing an escape character, an
>   application cannot be sure whether to treat it as an escape key press
>   or whether to expect more characters to complete a longer keycode.
>
> Therefore they tend to employ a timeout to decide. The delay on the
>   escape key can be annoying though, particularly with the
>   mode-dependent cursor above enabled. The timeout approach can also
>   fail on slow connections or a heavily loaded machine.
>
> Mintty’s “application escape key mode” can be used to avoid this by
>   switching the escape key to an unambiguous keycode. Add the following
>   to ~/.vimrc to employ it in vim:
>
> ```
> let &t_ti.="\e[?7727h"
> let &t_te.="\e[?7727l"
> noremap <Esc>O[ <Esc>
> noremap! <Esc>O[ <Esc>
> ```

### 2. possibly related question in SO: [vim mintty/putty mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23971202/717124)

> You can try to set the [terminal's
>   keycodes](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim)
>   to vim's keycodes like this:
>
> ```
> set <c-tab>=^[[1;5I
> ```

Similar to the description of that question, you can verify what Vim receives when you press the code following the steps at [`Vim faq-20.4`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq%2d20%2e4).

Comment: Thanks, reading again through the mintty tips solved the problem.
The *TERM* variable was set to *cygwin*, which is needed to solve some other problems, but leads to *vim* not recognizing the keysequences.
Startying *vim* with *-T xterm* solves the problem.

Regarding 2.: If you look into the code in the original post, you will find that it does exactly what your code also does. Problem is that it does not work for some of the keys.

Comment: @LaReine great, I'm glad you figured it out!